# Why does this Python async script never finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I created a MCVE example of a much larger code base that I am working on, so some things look to be a funky way of doing things, but they are just the minimal versions, so not everything makes sense as far as WHY I am doing it this way. I already know some work-arounds, and at this point am mostly just curious as to why I am seeing this behaviour.

I have the following script which has an async function that waits for a future. The script then intercepts a signal to set the future result:

```
import asyncio
import time
import signal

f = asyncio.Future()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def wait_till_signal():
    await f

def send_stop():
    print('stopping', time.time())
    f.set_result(True)
    print('sent')
    print(f.result())

def handle_signal(s, a):
    print('sending stop', time.time())
    send_stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)

loop.run_until_complete(wait_till_signal())
```

This script correctly gets the interrupt, and appears to set the future correctly, but for some reason the script never terminates.

To reproduce for you, just run the script, then hit ctrl+c. For some reason it never stops.

Now here is where it gets weird. If you add the following to the top of the script (after defining the loop), then the script stops just fine.

```
async def do_nothing_useful():
     for i in range(30):
         await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop.create_task(do_nothing_useful())
```

Why is the coroutine not getting the future in the first case, but it gets it correctly in the second case?

---

Also, another weird thing is that if you set the `send_stop` function to be async, and add it as a task, it never gets called. (This follows the same behaviour as above. If the do_nothing_useful() function is on the loop, everything works fine, but without it, it doesnt)

Here is the version where the send_stop is never called:

```
import asyncio
import time
import signal

f = asyncio.Future()

async def wait_till_signal():
    await f

async def send_stop():
    # this is async only because we are trying to try out crazy things
    print('stopping', time.time())
    f.set_result(True)
    print('sent')
    print(f.result())


def handle_signal(s, a):
    print('sending stop', time.time())
    loop.create_task(send_stop())


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(wait_till_signal())
print('done')
```

and the script never prints `stopping`.

---

I have tried this on python 3.5.3 and 3.6 on linux

Comment: just out of curiosity, what operating system are you running this on?

Comment: @user1767754 linux

Answer (score 3):

The correct method to add a signal handler that wakes up a loop is by using [`loop.add_signal_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_signal_handler). This will make sure `select()` wakes up to handle the signal.

Comment: Yep. That works great. Any idea why setting the result isnt triggering anything though?